# How do I use the Lagrange multiplier in this problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have this problem:

```
max     f(x,y)
s.t    2x + 4y = 3
```

If the function $f(x,y) = x^{0.7}y^{0.3}$ then how can I use Lagrange multiplier to find the maximum input choices? I found out that $\nabla$$g(x,y) = 2i + 4j$ and $\nabla$$f(x,y) = 0.7(y/x)^{0.3} + 0.3(x/y)^{0.7}$. So I know that $\nabla$f = λ$\nabla$g but how do I use these numbers to find the maximum input choices?

Comment: One line solution: differentiate $$x^a(3-2x)^b,$$ leading to the condition $$\frac{a}x-\frac{2b}{3-2x}=0,$$ thus the maximum is at $$x=\frac{3a}{2(a+b)},$$ which, using $a+b=1$, shows that $$\max\limits_{2x+4y=3} f(x,y)=2^{a-2}a^a(1-a)^{1-a}.$$ This isa slightly disguised version of the fact (which might be worth remembering) that, for every $a$ in $(0,1)$, the multiple of the beta density $$x^a(1-x)^{1-a}$$ is maximum at $x=a$ where its value is $$a^a(1-a)^{1-a}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$F=x^{7/10} y^{3/10}+\lambda  (2 x+4 y-3)$$ compute the derivatives and set them equal to zero $$F'_x=2 \lambda +\frac{7 y^{3/10}}{10 x^{3/10}}=0$$ $$F'_y=4 \lambda +\frac{3 x^{7/10}}{10 y^{7/10}}=0$$ $$F'_\lambda=2 x+4 y-3=0$$ From $F'_x=0$, you can extract $$\lambda=-\frac{7 y^{3/10}}{20 x^{3/10}}$$ Replacing $\lambda$ in $F'_y$, you get $$F'_y=\frac{3 x^{7/10}}{10 y^{7/10}}-\frac{7 y^{3/10}}{5 x^{3/10}}=\frac{3 x-14 y}{10 x^{3/10} y^{7/10}}=0$$ which makes $$3x-14y=0$$ Combine this with $F'_\lambda$ : two linear equation for two unknowns $x,y$. Solve and compute the value of $x^{7/10} y^{3/10}$.

At first glance, I thought that the problem is simple because the sum of the exponents is equal to $1$. Effectively, making it more general such as $$F=x^{a} y^{1-a}+\lambda  (2 x+4 y-3)$$ just doing the same, you should arrive to $$(1-a)x-2ay=0$$

But, the problem stays simple if set as $$F=x^{a} y^{b}+\lambda  (2 x+4 y-3)$$ Repeat the same steps to arrive to $b x-2ay=0$.

I am sure than you can take it from here.

Comment: So if I use the equation I got in the end combined with the equation for F′λ then would be critical points be (3.15, 0.225) or did I make some calculation error?

Comment: @JoshSusa. Calculation errors.

Comment: So to find the critical points, do I have to combine the equations 3x-14y = 0 and 2x + 4y - 3 = 0 and just take those equations as they are to find the critical points for x and y?

Answer (score -1):

during the step
Replacing λ in F'y, 
you divided the denominator by 4 because of 4λ. Can you actually do this? It seems like it would change the value.

Comment: i got (1.05,0.225)